# Spring Boot static suffix removal

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

is there a way to remap requests to static content in spring boot to remove a suffix (for example). for example, if i have a resource
`/static/file/policy.html` and i want to map requests to `/policy` to that file is there a way i could do it? something like:

```java
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        var r = registry.addResourceHandler("/policy", "/file/policy.html");
   }
```

or to specify a fallback like use `file:/var/thumbnails/default.png` if the desired image is not in `file:/var/thumbnails`:

```java
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        var r = registry.addResourceHandler("/thumbnails/*")
                        .addResourceLocation("file:/var/thumbnails/")
                        .defaultLocation("file:/var/thumbnails/default.png");
   }
```